# program not returning proper results for RadioButton

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

When I run the code below, the first 2 buttons do not appear; however, the third one is visible in the frame.

```
public class RadioButton {
    RadioButton(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JRadioButton button1 = new JRadioButton("One");
        button1.setBounds(50, 20, 50, 20);
        JRadioButton button2 = new JRadioButton("Two");
        button2.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 20);
        JRadioButton button3 = new JRadioButton("Three");
        button2.setBounds(50, 80, 50, 20);
        ButtonGroup bg  = new ButtonGroup();
        bg.add(button1);
        bg.add(button2);
        bg.add(button3);
        frame.add(button1);
        frame.add(button2);
        frame.add(button3);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RadioButton();
    }

}
```

Comment: I note you set the bounds twice on button2 and never on button3. Typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess since the OP set the layout manager to null, absolute positioning was what was wanted. This is not usually recommended. See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html).

You need to re-order the code as follows - i.e set the layout *before* setting the bounds of the components.

```
public class RadioButton {

RadioButton() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JRadioButton button1 = new JRadioButton("One");
    JRadioButton button2 = new JRadioButton("Two");
    JRadioButton button3 = new JRadioButton("Three");
    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    frame.setLayout(null);
    bg.add(button1);
    bg.add(button2);
    bg.add(button3);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.add(button1);
    frame.add(button2);
    frame.add(button3);
    button1.setBounds(50, 20, 80, 20);
    button2.setBounds(50, 50, 80, 20);
    button3.setBounds(50, 80, 80, 20);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new RadioButton();
}
}
```

I am using OS X and I needed to make the buttons a bit bigger to avoid their captions being displayed as '...'. Finally I used `invokeLater`, which IIRC is best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a layout manager for the container, I suggest you read the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

```
RadioButton(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JRadioButton button1 = new JRadioButton("One");
    JRadioButton button2 = new JRadioButton("Two");
    JRadioButton button3 = new JRadioButton("Three");
    ButtonGroup bg  = new ButtonGroup();
    bg.add(button1);
    bg.add(button2);
    bg.add(button3);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(button1);
    frame.add(button2);
    frame.add(button3);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The default layout for `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`.  Without specifying a region, each component you add is being placed into `BorderLayout.CENTER`.  Since button3 was the last to be added, it replaced button2 (button2 replaced button1 when it was added).  You could create a `JPanel` using `FlowLayout`, and add the three buttons there.  Then add the `JPanel` to the `JFrame`.